# What's the synonym for "not briefly"?

Tags: word-request

I want to refer a friend to an article and to tell him that the topic he's looking for is explained 'not briefly'. But I'm using "not briefly" because don't know to say it in a positive way (without using the word 'not').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The article deals with the topic **at length**." Or, "at great length", or "thoroughly" or "completely".  You might also search the web for antonyms of "briefly".